# How to display labels in the Outlook taskpane VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an **Outlook addin** like Grammerly,I addeed a ribbon button for checking the spelling and a taskpane for showing the errors.I have used **NHunspell** plugin to check spelling mistakes.
The problem is when i clicking the checking button it will successfully found the errors but the error could not display it in the taskpane.

this is how i added taskpane in **InspecterWrapper class**

```
public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomtask;
objsidepane = new SidePane();
myCustomtask = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(objsidepane, "Taskpane");
```

Here is the CheckButton click function.

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
       Display("checked");
    }
```

in the sidepane i have this function and i have a label in tskpane

```
public void Display(String s)
    {
        Label1.Text=s;
    }
```

actually the value is getting here but it not changing the label.

Comment: Why are the tags for Word in your question, and not Outlook?

Comment: Sorry its Outlook only, I have changed now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the `Visible` property of the task pane class to `true`.

```
 public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomtask;
 objsidepane = new SidePane();
 myCustomtask = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(objsidepane, "Taskpane");
 myCustomtask.Visible = true;
```

See [How to: Add a Custom Task Pane to an Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application) for more information.

Also you can show the task pane dynamically by setting the Visible property in the `Display` method:

```
public void Display(String s)
{
    myCustomtask.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text=s;
}
```

Read more about that in the 
[Walkthrough: Synchronizing a Custom Task Pane with a Ribbon Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-synchronizing-a-custom-task-pane-with-a-ribbon-button) .

Comment: the taskpane is visible there ,my actual problem is the label is not renderd inside the taskpane.

Comment: How did you add it?

Comment: public class InspectorWrapper
    {
       public static Outlook.Inspector inspector;
       public CustomTaskPane taskPane;
        public InspectorWrapper()
        {

        }
        public InspectorWrapper(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            inspector = Inspector;
            taskPane = Globals.WritingAssistant.CustomTaskPanes.Add(
                new SidePane(), "taskpane", inspector);
            taskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(TaskPane_VisibleChanged);
            taskPane.Width = 360;
}
}

Comment: Did you add a label control to the `UserControl.Controls` collection?